# Delete the node before the given node

Tags: java, data-structures

I have the code to delete a specific node but I cannot delete the node before a given node. Any ideas on how to do it with this function? (Solution below)

```
void deleBefore(Node q) {
    if (q == null || q == head) {
        return;
    }

    Node p = null;
    Node n = head;
    while (n != null && n.next != q) {
        p = n;
        n = n.next;
    }
    if (n == null) {
        return;
    }

    if (n == head) {
        head = q;
    } else {
        p.next = q;
    }
```

Node class

```
public class Node {

Boat info;
Node next;

Node() {
}

Node(Boat x, Node p) {
    info = x;
    next = p;
}

Node(Boat x) {
    this(x, null);
}
```

}

Comment: Check if the `next node` is your required node. If so, delete the current node. Map the previous node's next to the required node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to keep track of the previous node as you iterate through the list looking for `q`, then update its `next` to `q`, if `q` was found, or update `head`.

```
void deleteBefore(Node q)
{
  if(q == null || q == head) return;

  Node p = null;
  Node n = head;
  while(n != null && n.next != q)
  {
    p = n;
    n = n.next;
  }
  if(n == null) 
    return;

  if(n == head) 
    head = q;
  else 
    p.next = q;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i modified your function, hope it helps

```
 void deletePrev(Node q)
 {if(q==null || q==head) return;

  Node p=head;
  while(p!=null && p.next.next!=q) p=p.next;
  if(p==null) return; // q is not in the list
  p.next = q;
  if(p.next.next==null) tail = p;
 }
```

Comment: Your function doesn't work, I have edited my function. Could you look it up for me, thanks.

Comment: @Hazem Ashraf What happens if you try and delete something that's not in the list?

Comment: jamefocus please mark my answer as the correct one

@sirRaffleBuffle this line for this case if(p==null) return;
if the node is not in the list p will be null after while loop

Comment: @Hazem Ashraf If you try and delete an element that's not in the list you'll get a `NullPointerException` when `p` is the last element.

Comment: @sirRaffle  soory for the late response, you are right, we have to check for that case, may modifying the while loop fix it while(p!=null && p.next.next!=q){
if ( p.next.next == null) return;
p=p.next;

}